# Install specific version of wp-cli package

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I would like to install a specific version of a wp-cli package, e.g.

```
wp package install geekpress/wp-rocket-cli@1.1
```

or if this does not work, then from a specific github commit

```
wp package install git@github.com:GeekPress/wp-rocket-cli.git#04ff23bbc3e293d44e8dde4ae64e1918f3e8534a
```

But both does not work. Is there a way to fix the version? 
I'm using wp-cli in an automated environment, and I do not want it to break, if a wp-cli package changes a command in it`s latest commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of WP-CLI version 2.5.0, the **separator** to be used between the package name and the desired version is a **colon**:

```
wp package install wp-cli-configmaps/wp-cli-configmaps:1.0.1
```

To verify it worked correctly, use the `wp package list` command - you should see your specified version in the output:

```
+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+----------------+
| name                                | authors             | version | update | update_version |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+----------------+
| wp-cli-configmaps/wp-cli-configmaps | Bostjan Skufca Jese | 1.0.1   | none   |                |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+----------------+
```

The relevant WP-CLI source code is [here](https://github.com/wp-cli/package-command/blob/a009ac4ac3c2c51014871f0acf0d2663cf3133e5/src/Package_Command.php#L289). This probably works with pre-2.5.0 WP-CLI versions too.

Comment: Thank you for this answer after 4 years! I'm not working with Wordpress anymore, but I hope this thread is helpful for somebody :)